# How is this solution to reversing words in a sentence O(N) when it calls reverse on the whole sentence and then reverse on each word?

Tags: python, string, algorithm

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-words-in-a-given-string/

How is this solution to reversing words in a sentence O(N) when it calls reverse on the whole sentence and then reverse on each word?

N = length of overall string
M = length of each string

Wouldn't it be O(N) + O(N*M)? Is it correct to use M to represent length of strings since M can be difference for each input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reusing `N` to mean two different things. Really there should be three variables:

- `N` is the length of the whole string
- `M` is the number of words in the string
- `O` is the (average) length of each word

Then your whole algorithm would run in `O(N + M*O)`. However, `M*O` is always going to be smaller than `N`, since the string is made up of the words and the spaces separating them. So you can simplify the whole thing to `O(N)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The average length of each word for O really helps. If the original input were list = ['foo', 'bar', 'hello', 'world'] and I was only reversing each word (not the whole list), the answer would be O(M*O), right?

Comment: Actually, `M*O == N`, since `O` is (by definition) `N/M`.

Comment: `M*O` is usually going to be slightly less than `N` in the general case, since there will be spaces between the words in the original string.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using N as the length of the entire string, then you shouldn't do N*M to represent reversing each word, it is just N, because you are going through the entire string itself twice: once to reverse it and once to reverse the individual words.

**EDIT:** If you were given a list of strings and you want to reverse the order of the list followed by a reversal of the strings themselves, then it would be O(N) + O(L*M), where N is the number of elements in the array and M is the length of the words, because the array is separate from the words. You can reverse the order of the array without reversing the words, so that is a separate calculation from the words. When you reverse the words it would be the length of the word times the number of words that you are reversing.

Comment: Isn't it different reversing the whole list for O(N) versus performing a reversal on each string in the whole list O(N*M)? What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you define as N? It's the length of the entire string. Why are you multiplying the length of the entire string by substrings of it? The second number you are looking for would be closer to L*M, L being the number of strings and M being the length of each. However, the number of substrings times the number of words brings us back to the original N

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks for clearing that up. Let's say the original input was this list of strings (list = ['foo', 'bar', 'hello', 'world'], would a reversal of the whole list be O(N) followed by a reversal of each element be O(N*M)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say original input = list of strings. Edited.

Comment: Edit your original question to ask that, so I can answer in the answer and not in a comment

Answer (score 0):

Look at what the code does:

1. It scans the entire sentence (N chars) looking for word boundaries.
2. For each word, it reverses the word. The reverse function loops W/2 times for W characters in word.
3. At the end, it reverses the entire string (N/2 loops).

The tricky part is the reversal of the words. Because the words are all part of the same sentence, you can look at them as simply another traversal of the entire sentence.

This makes it:

1. O(n)
2. O(n)
3. O(n)

So the whole thing is O(3n), which is O(n).